# Need a fast method to convert large amount of double to string

Tags: c, postgresql, hpc

I am writing a results output module for a high speed computing program.

My plan is:

1. My task is to insert the results into database (PostgreSQL) with relative fast speed.
2. I use [COPY FROM STDIN] of libpq, which I was told as the fastest way.
3. The method requires converting the results into char* format.

While the results looks like this:

1. Monthly CashFlow for next 106 years (1272 double in Total).
2. Around 14 CashFlows for each entiry.
3. Around 2800 entities (2790 for tested data).

And the table in database looks like this:

1. Each row of the table contains one entity.
2. There are some prefix to identify different entities.
3. CashFlows are double array that follows the prefix (float8[] type in PGSQL).

The following present the code for creating the table in database:

```
create table AgentCF(
PlanID     int4,
Agent      int4,
Senario    int4,
RM_Prev    float8[], DrvFac_Cur float8[], Prem       float8[],
Comm       float8[], CommOR     float8[], FixExp     float8[],
VarExp     float8[], CIRCFee    float8[], SaftyFund  float8[],
Surr       float8[], Benefit_1  float8[], Benefit_2  float8[],
Benefit_3  float8[], Benefit_4  float8[], Benefit_5  float8[],
Benefit_6  float8[], Benefit_7  float8[], Benefit_8  float8[],
Benefit_9  float8[], Benefit_10 float8[]
);
```

Presenting code for function that prepare the inserted CashFlow:

```
void AsmbCF(char *buffer, int size, int ProdNo, int i, int Pos, int LineEnd)
{
    int     j, Step = sizeof(nodecf) / sizeof(double), PosST, Temp;
    double *LoopRate = &AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].CF.NodeCF[0].Prem;
    strcpy_s(buffer, size, "{");
    for (j = 0; j < TOTLEN / 10; j++) {
        PosST = j * 10 * Step + Pos;
        sprintf_s(&buffer[strlen(buffer)], size - strlen(buffer), "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,",
            LoopRate[PosST],
            LoopRate[PosST + 1 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 2 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 3 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 4 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 5 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 6 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 7 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 8 * Step],
            LoopRate[PosST + 9 * Step]
        );
    }
    Temp = j * 10;
    PosST = Temp * Step + Pos;
    sprintf_s(&buffer[strlen(buffer)], size - strlen(buffer), "%f", LoopRate[PosST]);
    Temp = Temp + 1;
    for (j = Temp; j < TOTLEN; j++) {
        PosST = j * Step + Pos;
        sprintf_s(&buffer[strlen(buffer)], size - strlen(buffer), ",%f", LoopRate[PosST]);
    }
    if (LineEnd) {
        strcat_s(buffer, size, "}\n");
    }
    else {
        strcat_s(buffer, size, "}\t");
    }
}
```

The following are the code for speed testing:

```
void ThreadOutP(LPVOID pM)
{
    char       *buffer = malloc(BUFFLEN), sql[SQLLEN];
    int         Status, ProdNo = (int)pM, i, j, ben;
    PGconn     *conn = NULL;
    PGresult   *res;
    clock_t     begin, end;

    fprintf_s(fpOutP, "PlanID %d Start inseting...\n", AllHeap[ProdNo].PlanID);
    begin = clock();
    DBConn(&conn, CONNSTR, fpOutP);

#pragma region General cashflow
    //============================== Data Query ==============================
    //strcpy_s(&sql[0], SQLLEN, "COPY AgentCF(PlanID,Agent,Senario,Prem,Comm,CommOR,CIRCFee,SaftyFund,FixExp,VarExp,Surr");
    //for (ben = 1; ben <= AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.TotNo.NoBenft; ben++) {
    //  strcat_s(&sql[0], SQLLEN, ",Benefit_");
    //  _itoa_s(ben, &sql[strlen(sql)], sizeof(sql) - strlen(sql), 10);
    //}
    //strcat_s(&sql[0], SQLLEN, ") FROM STDIN;");
    //res = PQexec(conn, &sql[0]);
    //if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COPY_IN) {
    //  fprintf_s(fpOutP, "Not in COPY_IN mode\n");
    //}
    //PQclear(res);
    //============================== Data Apply ==============================
    for (i = 0; i < AllHeap[ProdNo].MaxAgntPos + AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.TotNo.NoSensi; i++) {
        sprintf_s(buffer, BUFFLEN, "%d\t%d\t%d\t", AllHeap[ProdNo].PlanID, AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].Agent, AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].Sensi);
        //Status = PQputCopyData(conn, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer));
        //if (1 != Status) {
        //  fprintf_s(fpOutP, "PlanID %d inserting error for agent %d\n", AllHeap[ProdNo].PlanID, AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].Agent);
        //}
        for (j = 0; j < 8 + AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.TotNo.NoBenft; j++) {
            if (j == 7 + AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.TotNo.NoBenft) {
                AsmbCF(buffer, BUFFLEN, ProdNo, i, j, 1);
            }
            else {
                AsmbCF(buffer, BUFFLEN, ProdNo, i, j, 0);
            }
            //Status = PQputCopyData(conn, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer));
            //if (1 != Status) {
            //  fprintf_s(fpOutP, "PlanID %d inserting error for agent %d\n", AllHeap[ProdNo].PlanID, AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].Agent);
            //}
        }
    }
    //Status = PQputCopyEnd(conn, NULL);
#pragma endregion

#pragma region K cashflow

#pragma endregion

    PQfinish(conn);
    FreeProd(ProdNo);
    free(buffer);
    end = clock();
    fprintf_s(fpOutP, "PlanID %d inserted, total %d rows inserted, %d millisecond cost\n", AllHeap[ProdNo].PlanID, i, end - begin);
    AllHeap[ProdNo].Printed = 1;
}
```

Please note that I disable the code that involving inserting.

The tested results are:

1. Cost of only assembling the string is 45930 millisecond.
2. Cost of assembling the string and insert is 54829 millisecond.

So the most of the cost lie on converting double to char.

Therefore I would like to ask if there is a faster way of converting series of double into string, because compare to the calculation cost, the bottleneck actually is the outputting of results.

By the way, my platform is Windows 10, PostgreSQL 11, Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You spend a lot of time on strlen() and strcat() [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm ]. Do you know that snprintf() returns a usable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fast method to convert large amount of double to string

For full `double` range application, use `sprintf(buf, "%a", some_double)`.  If decimal output required, use `"%e"`.

Any other code will only be faster if it is comprises accuracy or allowable input range *somehow*.

The *usual* approach is to convert `double x` to some wide scaled integer and convert that to a string.  This implies limitations on `x` not clearly expressed yet by OP.

Even if some other approaches appears faster, it may not be faster as code evolves or is ported.

---

What OP needs to post is speed test code for objective performance assessment.

Comment: A "full double" means double without decimal?? I'll try %e now, also I'll try to write a code using itoa, since I'm using intel's cpu, there should be fild instruction.

Comment: @Shore "full double range" does not mean _double without decimal_.  A typical `double` has about 2^64 different values.  The fast output should do a good job for all of them (the _full range_), not just a select few.  Otherwise, if the fast output needs to exists for a sub-range of `double`, clearly state that range and accuracy needed.

Comment: I may only need 6-7 decimal point, however if I just use sprinf with %f, it would only output 6 decimal point......

Comment: @Shore "if I just use sprinf with %f, it would only output 6 decimal point..." -->  Is often wasteful, uninformative or mis-leading.  _floating-point_ is called _floating_-point for a reason.  The precision _floats_.  123456789012234567890.123456 is often good enough as 1.23456e19 for 6 diigts of precision where as 0.0000000000123456 is best as 1.23456e-19.  With `"%f,"` output can get the uninformative `"123456789012234567890.123456"`vs the tidy `'1.23456e19"` and `"0.000000"` vs. `"1.23456e-19"`.  In other words, with `"%f"` is either wasteful or uninformative.

Comment: @shore To get faster than `"%a"` and has useful output, you need to specify the limitations of output.  "only need 6-7 decimal point," is insufficient for a good answer.

Comment: Well, %a will convert them to HEX value............... However, I made a function use itoa, make the conversion cost to around 4.5 second, which is good enough for me, lol.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually several faster methods for accurately representing floating point numbers as strings, one of them is [Grisu, by Florian Loitsch](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220752315_Printing_Floating-Point_Numbers_Quickly_and_Accurately_with_Integers).

[This github repo](https://github.com/miloyip/dtoa-benchmark) compares several algorithms in C and C++, and it contains the [source code for the Grisu2 method in C](https://github.com/miloyip/dtoa-benchmark/tree/master/src/grisu), which he claims to be 5.7x faster than `sprintf`.

However, the author of the same repo ([Milo Yip](https://github.com/miloyip)) provides his own C++ single header implementation which is claimed to be 9.1x faster, presumably since more of the functions are completely inlined. I believe porting this code to C should be trivial, since it doesn't use any special C++ syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I did some bookkeeping on the original code:

---

```
  Total score("function" calls):
    2 + 4*TOTLEN * strlen()
    1 + 2*TOTLEN * sprintf() 
    1 * strcat()

  Estimated string() cost:
    3 + 4* size * (TOTLEN*TOTLEN) / 2 (measured in characters)

  Estimated sprintf() cost:
    2 * TOTLEN (measured in %lf conversions)
    2 * size (measured in characters)
```

---

Now, I dont know what `TOTLEN` is, but calling strlen() and friends on a ever growing string results in quadratic behaviour, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm

---

- profile/measure (or think) before you optimise
- `snprintf()` , when used correctly, is overflow-safe; read the manual page and use the return value
- the `strxxx_x()` functions are nearly useless, they only exist to please the PHBs

Comment: BTW, I underestimated the string cost (by a factor of 4) Can you find it?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to chux's answer, I made the following function:

```
__inline char* dbltoa(char* buff, double A, int Precision)
{
    int     Temp;
    char   *ptr;

    Temp = (int)A;
    _itoa_s(Temp, buff, 50, 10);
    ptr = buff + strlen(buff);
    ptr[0] = '.';
    Temp = (int)((A - Temp) * pow(10, Precision));
    _itoa_s(Temp, ptr + 1, 50, 10);
    return ptr + strlen(ptr);
}
```

And updated the function that make the CashFlow string:

```
void AsmbCF(char *buffer, int size, int ProdNo, int i, int Pos, int LineEnd)
{
    int     j, Step = sizeof(nodecf) / sizeof(double), PosST, Temp;
    double *LoopRate = &AllHeap[ProdNo].Heap.AgentRes[i].CF.NodeCF[0].Prem;
    char   *ptr;
    strcpy_s(buffer, size, "{");
    ptr = buffer + 1;
    for (j = 0; j < TOTLEN; j++) {
        PosST = j * Step + Pos;
        ptr = dbltoa(ptr, LoopRate[PosST], 8);
        ptr[0] = ',';
        ptr++;
    }
    ptr[-1] = 0;
    if (LineEnd) {
        strcat_s(buffer, size, "}\n");
    }
    else {
        strcat_s(buffer, size, "}\t");
    }
}
```

The tested result without insert is 4558 millisecond, while with insert tooks 29260 millisecond (probably parallel running of the database made this nonequivalent by ratio).

Comment: This "answer" only does `TOTLEN` conversions, the original did **twice as many**. So, you could *at least* multiply this result by two. (and: I expect a `snprintf()` based solution not to be much slower)