# How can I find the shortest representation of a floating-point number

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

If I try to print a floating-point value with maximum precision for the type, such as:

```
printf("%.100e", FLT_MIN);
```

I get this:

```
1.1754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625000000000000e-38
```

However, if I try to print something like this (I changed the last digits of the mantissa):

```
float x = 1.1754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515610e-38f;
printf("%.100e", x);
```

Then the output is the same:

```
1.1754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625000000000000e-38
```

This is because there is no exact representation for the value I put in, so it got rounded.

The question is: how can I find the shortest value (in terms of digits) which rounds to the same number?

Comment: Searching Stack Overflow for “grisu3” or “dragon4” shows relevant information.

Comment: Notably see [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately with Integers](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf), although I think there may be more recent work. Note that implementing the algorithms requires some skill with floating-point in a variety of ways (in addition to familiarity with the floating-point standard, knowing how your compiler behaves with floating-point).

Comment: If you want a short, slow, and stupid implementation, then obviously you can use `snprintf` to print the number to a buffer with one significant digit (`%.1g`), the convert that numeral back to the floating-point type and see if it is the same. If not, try again with one more digit. Repeat until the number survives the round trip. This of course requires that your C implementation provide correct rounding in these conversions. Apple’s library does. The C implementation recommends it (up to the number of digits you will need for any format the implementation supports)  but does not require it.

Comment: "how can I find the shortest value (in terms of digits) which rounds to the same number?" --> Use `printf("%.e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, some_float);` for a beginning step.  Might be able to do with less, but no case will need more than this.  Other approach, look to `"%g"` and `"%a"`.

Comment: Correction: “The C implementation recommends it” above should be “The C standard recommends it.”

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955946/298225) links to Github repositories with algorithms in C and C++.

Comment: If you choose to go @EricPostpischil's route with a `for` loop of `snprintf` + `atof` to determine the optimal precision, note that `%.17g` can be used as an upper bound (assuming that your C implementation uses IEEE 754 `double` and rounds correctly).

Answer (score 1):

You could use hexdecimal floating point number introduced in C99.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float x = 1.1754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625000000000000e-38;
    printf("%a\n", x); // prints 0x1p-126
    float hx = 0x1p-126;
    printf("%a\n", hx); // prints 0x1p-126
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I know, but I would like it in base 10 (E notation).